# I want to use "applicationWillEnterForeground", however my function requires an UIImageView and I can't call on it in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an image on a website, and I want it to be put into a UIImageView, however I want it to refresh every time the application is launched.

I have the following code in a ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        get_image("WEBSITE.com/image.jpg", image)
 
    }
    func get_image(_ url_str:String, _ imageView:UIImageView)
    {
        
        let url:URL = URL(string: url_str)!
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
            (
            data, response, error) in
            

            if data != nil
            {
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)

                if(image != nil)
                {
                
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    
                        imageView.image = image
                        imageView.alpha = 0
                        
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, animations: {
                            imageView.alpha = 1.0
                        })
                    })
                }
            }
        })
        
        task.resume()
    }
    
}
```

Since the image in WEBSITE.com/image.jpg is going to change often, I wan't the app to pull the image everytime it launches. I did some research, and was told to put the following code into my AppDelegate.

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    ViewController().get_image("WEBSITE.com/image.jpg", image)
   }
```

However, after the link, the "image" doesn't work. How do I reference the image in the AppDelegate file?

BTW, I get the following error message:
"Cannot convert value of type 'module' to expected argument type 'UIImageView'"

What do I do?

Comment: You are creating a new instance of your view controller, which will be thrown away almost immediately.  You would be better off having your view controller observe the `willEnterForeground` `Notification`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the observer pattern to let ViewController know when the app will enter the foreground.

`UIScene` has a built in notification that you can simply observe from within the `viewDidLoad` of your view controller.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(get_image), name: UIScene.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
 
}
```

The selector is the action taken whenever your view controller observes `willEnterForegroundNotification`. In order to use `get_image` as a selector you will also need to expose it to the Objective-C runtime by writing `@Objc` before the `func` keyword.

Comment: A few notes not a part of the answer. I would recommend trying to separate your Logic from the UI in the future. Requests to the internet aren't typically done directly in view controllers. Also, Swift convention is to use lowerCamelCase for methods (`getImage`).

Comment: `UIScene.willEnterForegroundNotification`

Comment: Wow that's convenient! Thank you. Updated answer accordingly